# When using the Button object in Tkinter I get an error

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, button

When running this code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Programma')
        self.geometry('500x400')

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Execute', command=self.fun)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=4, stick=tk.W)

        def fun(self):
            print('Hello')
        
        

app = MyApplication()
app.mainloop()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Andrea/Desktop/hfhfhg.py", line 17, in <module>
    app = MyApplication()   File "C:/Users/Andrea/Desktop/hfhfhg.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Execute', command=self.fun)   File "C:\WPy64-3910\python-3.9.1.amd64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2346, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr) AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'fun'
```

I understand that the code is not optimal for a GUI but I would like to understand how Tkinter works without using a frame object. Please can you help me?

Comment: wrong Indentation here -> `def fun(self):`

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks a lot!